# TFS Power Tools - WIT Designer toolbox missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

In Visual Studio 2010, I installed the TFS Power Tools, which also included the WIT Designer. Once I open my User Story work item editor and click on the "Workflow" tab, I should be able to see the "WITDesigner" toolbox items in the Toolbox, but it is missing. I tried the "Reset Toolbox" option, but it that didn't work either. I did verify that the "WITDesigner" was installed in the Extension Manager. Any ideas of how I can get the items to show up? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I had to uninstall all TFS related extensions and reaplly SP1. Then I could reinstall the TFS Power Tools and the WIT designer now shows up.